# Vue - How to get value from URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this url structure:

http://localhost:3000/apps/projects/update/5

How can I get the number 5 from the URL using Vue JS way?

I am trying with this code:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to [add vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html) to your project. Then you can define [dynamic routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), like:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/apps/project/:id', component: Project },
]
```

In this example, the `:id` defines a dynamic parameter. Than, in the Project component you can use the id variable:

```
const route = useRoute()
const urlParams = route.params.id;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Than You Gabe...